# Matrix with known entries but unknown size

Tags: matrix

I am trying to perform some calculations with a matrix that has let's say size N but unknown, please How can I write this in mathematica?

[image: This is the matrix in question]

Comment: Look up `SparseArray[]` and `Band[]`.

Answer (score 7):

The following function, along the lines of the suggestion by Guesswhoitis, produces what you appear to want.

```
m[r_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> n, Band[{2, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> -2}, {r, r}]
```

It is unclear whether the `n` in the picture is the same as `n`, the dimension of the matrix.  (Do not use `N`, which is a reserved term.)  If not, change `Band[{1, 1}] -> n` to `Band[{1, 1}] -> whateveryouwant`.  As a sample result,

```
m[5] // Normal
(* {{n, -2, 0, 0, 0}, {-2, n, -2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, n, -2, 0}, 
    {0, 0, -2, n, -2}, {0, 0, 0, -2, n}} *)
```

Edit:  In light of the OP's comment, I have changed the dimension to `r` while leaving the matrix diagonal elements `n`, now unspecified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I misleaded you with the "N", the square matrix K is of size r x r ; with r arbitrary. 
I have a formulae that I want to compute: 

Formulae= V_transpose * K * V

with V a vector of dimension "r" such that V=(1,0,0,..,0).

Comment: @Zakariae, that's just the element in the first row and first column, no?

Comment: It was the inverse of K, I typed the code below where there is an error

In[45]:= v[r_] := UnitVector[r, 1];
m[r_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> n, Band[{2, 1}] -> -2, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> -2}, {r, r}];
Formulae[r_] := v[r].Inverse[m[r]].v[r];
Formulae[2]

Out[48]= n/(n^2-4)

In[49]:= Formulae[Q]

During evaluation of In[49]:= SparseArray::adims: Array dimension specification {Q,Q} should be Automatic, a non-negative machine integer, or a list of non-negative machine integers. >>

Out[49]= UnitVector[Q,1].SparseArray[{Band[{1,1}]->n,Band[{2,1}]->-2,Band[{1,2}]->-2},{Q,Q}]^-1.UnitVector[Q,1]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming *bbgodfrey*'s interpretation, I'd also expect this to be faster if dimension is large:

```
ToeplitzMatrix[PadRight[{#, -2}, #]] &
```

Though more memory hungry, it produces a packed array, so depending on what you're doing, it may have some performance benefits in use compared to a sparse realization (but the reverse could also be true, again, depends on what you're doing with it after creation).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `DiagonalMatrix` and its optional third argument

```
n = 5; 
mat[n_]:= DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[n, n]] + 
 DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-2, n - 1], 1] + 
 DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-2, n - 1], -1];
```